# Почему вызываются два исключения?

Tags: python, django, исключения

Есть код в представлении. Если такого элемента нет в модели (в базе данных), то должно вызываться стандартное исключение.

```
Entry.objects.get(id=-999) # raises Entry.DoesNotExist
```

Но на практике вызывается еще одно исключение, что такого поля в модели нет и вылетает ошибка:

```
type object 'Coupon' has no attribute 'DoesNotExists'
```

Почему?

```
@require_POST
def coupon_apply(request):
    now = timezone.now()
    form = CouponApplyForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        code = form.cleaned_data['code']
        try:
            coupon = Coupon.objects.get(code__iexact=code,
                                        valid_from__lte=now,
                                        valid_to__gte=now,
                                        active=True)
            request.session['coupon_id'] = coupon.id
        except Coupon.DoesNotExists:
            request.session['coupon_id'] = None
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')
```

Answer (score 1):

Подсказали. Опечатка:
DoesNotExist
DoesNotExists
Вопрос закрыт.